# how to solve the html binding problem in knockout?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, knockout.js

Let's take an example

### First Scenario

```
var s = "Hello <span>World</span>" 
<span  data-bind="html: s" />
```

after html binding the outcome is coming properly with the value "Hello World" in UI.

### 2nd Scenario

```
var s = "<DBD>hello <span>World</span>"
<span  data-bind="html: s" />
```

After binding the outcome is coming with the value "Hello World" in UI. But the outcome I want In UI is `"<DBD>Hello World"`.

I want only span tag needs for html binding other dummy text inside `"<>"` no need to bind it .simple text needs to show on UI.

Comment: how can this be answered

Comment: There is no code in the question

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! We would be able to see the issue only if you post it in your question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly

Comment: The question is now updated. sorry for the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
var s = "<DBD>hello <span>World</span>"
```

...`s` is not valid HTML. If you're wanting the literal text `<DBD>` to appear, you have to HTML-encode it:

```
var s = "&lt;DBD&gt;hello <span>World</span>"
```